# Prove that $\mu = 0.$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional NLS and $\mu$ be a translation invariant measure on $\mathcal B(X)$ such that $\mu (F) \lt \infty$ for all $F \in \mathcal B (X)$ with finite diameter. Then show that $\mu = 0.$

How do I proceed? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Thats not true, consider for example the counting measure. Unless with $F$ finite you really mean $F$ having finite diameter?

Comment: @s.harp you are right. There is a typo. I will edit it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $X=\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb N} B_n(0)$ where $B_n(0)$ is the ball of radius $n$ around. Hence if $\mu(X)\neq0$ at least one of these balls has to have non-zero mass. Let $B_n(0)$ denote such a ball.

Now for any finite dimensional sub-space $V$ you can find an element $x\notin V$ of norm $≤4 n$ and so that $\|y-x\|≥2n$ for all $y\in V$. Use this to iteratively find a sequence $x_i$ so that $\|x_i\|≤4n$ and $\|x_i-x_j\|≥2n$ for all $i\neq j$. This means that the balls $B_n(x_i)$ are all disjoint and are further contained in the ball $B_{5n}(0)$.

Hence:
$$\infty > \mu(B_{5n}(0) ) ≥ \mu\left(\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N} B_n(x_i)\right) =\sum_{i\in\Bbb N} \mu\left( x_i + B_n(0)\right) = \sum_{i\in\Bbb N} \mu \left ( B_n(0) \right ) = \infty$$
by translation invariance, a contradiction.

Comment: How do you get such an $x$ with $\|x\| \leq 4n$ and $\|y - x\| \geq 2n,\ $ for all $y \in V\ $? In fact $y = x$ will violate the later inequality.

Comment: I think you mean for all $y \not\in V$ for the later inequality.

Comment: The element $x$ is not in $V$. As to how to get it: Consider $[x]\in X/V$ of norm $2n$. This means that $\inf_{y\in V}\|x-y\|$ is equal to $2n$. So you can find a representant $x-y$ having norm $≤4n$, but the distance of this representant to $V$ is greater than $2n$ by the same formula.

Comment: How do you know that $[x]$ will be of norm $2n\ $?

Comment: $X/V$ is not zero because $V$ is finite dimensional and $X$ is not (further it is Banach because $V$ is closed). Take some non-zero vector in $X/V$ and just rescale it to have norm $2n$.

Comment: My professor also told something similar to that. He said that if $X$ is infinite dimensional then for any $\delta \gt 0$ there exist infinitely many disjoint balls $B_n \left (\frac {\delta} {4} \right )$ of radius $\frac {\delta} {4}$ contained in the ball $B (\delta)$ of radius $\delta$ centered at the origin. But I didn't get the point.

Comment: Its the same proof - if one of those balls of radius $\delta/4$ has non-zero measure they all do and hence $B(\delta)$ has infinite masure. A contradiction, it follows that the balls of radius $\delta/4$ have zero measure for any $\delta$.

Comment: I have seen a version of this proof for separable normed linear space which assumes the underlying measure to be locally finite and translation invariant. Here it is $:$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure Now a question comes into my mind. What will happen if the underlying normed linear space is not separable? Can we get a non-trivial locally finite translation invariant measure on a non-separable normed linear space?

Comment: The non-separable case is not nice. I guess there is enough infinity to hide such a measure. This note claims to give an example, I have not read it https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.2858.pdf